# Accessing the Twitter API using Mathematica 11

Tags: web-access, social-media, networking, authentication

The built-in social media functions are limited, so I'm using Twitter's web API for my work.

The following function worked for me when I was using versions of Mathematica earlier than 10.3.

```
token=HTTPClient`OAuthToken[HTTPClient`OAuth`Private`OAuth10Parameters[ 
    "api.twitter.com", None, Automatic, "verifier", Automatic, Automatic, 
    consumerKey, consumerSecret,
    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", 
    "GET", "https://www.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",
    "RemoveWhitespace", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token", 
    "GET", "HMAC-Sha1", "HMAC", "oob", "Text/1.0", "Text/1.0", None],
    HTTPClient`OAuth`Private`Token10[ accessToken, accessTokenSecret]];
url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
URLFetch[url, "OAuthAuthentication" -> token]
```

But when I upgraded to Mathematica 11, that code stopped working and gave error messages like the following:

> OAuthSigning`OAuthSignURL::nopt: The option OAuthAuthentication is missing in OAuthSigning`Private`OAuthURLFetchList[https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&q=%23brexit, {CredentialsProvider -> None, OAuthAuthentication -> OAuthSigning`OAuthAuthentication[HTTPClient`OAuthToken[HTTPClient`OAuth`Private`OAuth10Parameters[api.twitter.com, None, Automatic, <<15>>, Text/1.0, None], <<1>>]]}].

I also tried the following:

```
token = HTTPClient`OAuthAuthentication[
    "ConsumerKey" -> "your_api_key", 
    "ConsumerSecret" -> "your_api_secret", 
    "RequestEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
    "AuthorizeEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize", 
    "AccessEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
URLFetch[url, "OAuthAuthentication" -> token]
```

I need my program to be up to date with the latest versions of Mathematica. Any idea where might the problem be?

Comment: Why not use [`ServiceConnect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/Twitter.html)?

Comment: It's limited and can't use complex queries. That's why the one who started the project started using HTTPClient and URLFetch

Comment: It looks like you are searching for tweets. You can use    ServiceExecute[con, "TweetSearch", {"Query" -> "Trump", "MaxItems" -> 4}] where 'con' is the connection object returned from ServiceConnect

Comment: Another thing I would like to mention is that, you are using the code which is called under the hood to fetch token from a service. As this is not exposed to users so you can expect the functions being changed/renamed in future versions, thus lead to the scenario which you are facing. Mathematica currently supports lots of requests(https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/Twitter.html) which you can use with ServiceConnect to fetch data from twitter. If you still need specific requests and if those are available in twitter api then we can implement that in future releases.

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I like to have a variable 'token' but do not understand how to get that from the above answer. The code that worked in 10: ``tokenFrank = HTTPClient`OAuthAuthentication[ "ConsumerKey" ->"XXX", "ConsumerSecret" ->"XXX", "RequestEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "AuthorizeEndpoint" -> "link to authorize", "AccessEndpoint" -> "link to access_token"];`` Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

#### Update

Here's a cleaner rewrite of my original:

First authenticate:

```
$so = ServiceConnect["Twitter", "New"];
```

Then extract:

```
ServiceConnections`Private`serviceAuthentication[$so[[-1, -1]]][[2]]

OAuthSigning`Private`Token10[
 "806596495344603136-CEWIkGjWYevKFKsUT7uJ5XCLoLWyON2",
 "NuE2kf4PjPNkzUCpb6dASqjMfMoXbE07ACTj7YImeMb1R"
 ]
```

Note, too, that if you just want to add requests to the Twitter service connection *you can do that*.

First do this:

```
FileNameJoin@{
   PacletFind["ServiceConnection_Twitter"][[1]]["Location"],
   "Kernel",
   "Twitter.m"
   } // SystemOpen
```

And add your requests as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147196/38205)

Note that these won't persist if WRI updates its connection though, in which case you'll have to copy the requests to the new paclet.

---

#### Update 2:

By the way, I think your original request would now look like:

```
token =
  OAuthSigning`Private`OAuthFlow[
   OAuthSigning`Private`OAuth10Parameters["api.twitter.com", None, 
    Automatic, "verifier", Automatic, Automatic, "consumerKey", "consumerSecret", 
    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "GET", 
    "https://www.twitter.com/oauth/authorize", "RemoveWhitespace", 
    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token", "GET", "HMAC-Sha1", 
    "HMAC", "oob", "Text/1.0", "Text/1.0", None
    ],
   OAuthSigning`Private`Token10["accessToken", "accessTokenSecret"]
   ];
```

---

#### Original

Rather than go down to the metal and do the auth oneself, you could also rely on Mathematica's built-in `ServiceConnect` and then scrape the necessary auth data from that.

Some spelunking led me to `` ServiceConnections`Private`serviceAuthentication `` which takes a UUID and returns the associated auth info, if the service is authenticated. So this a feasible way to get that data.

It returns an `` OAuthSigning`OAuthToken `` object which appears to be the OAuth parameters and the token.

Using the following function I was able to get auth data that may be usable:

```
With[{service = ServiceConnect["Twitter"]},
 While[
  ("ID" /. Last@service // 
     ServiceConnections`Private`serviceAuthentication) === {},
  "Lock"];
 With[{data = ("ID" /. Last@service // 
      ServiceConnections`Private`serviceAuthentication)},
  <|
   "Parameters" -> First@data,
   "Token" -> Last@data
   |>
  ]
 ]
```

this returned and object that looked like `` OAuthSigning`OAuthToken[<<"Twitter OAuth 1.0">>] `` which is an elided form for the following:

```
OAuthSigning`OAuthToken[OAuthSigning`Private`OAuth10Parameters["Twitter", None, 
  Automatic, "verifier", Automatic, OAuthClient`oauthChannelVerify[#1, 
    {"Twitter", "connection-6f1c5e584c496a5101d61d0925eeadea"}] & , "Wolfram", "Token", 
  "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "GET", 
  "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize", "RemoveWhitespace", 
  "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token", "GET", "HMAC-Sha1", "HMAC", "https://ww\
w.wolfram.com/oauthlanding/connector/?connectionid=connection-6f1c5e584c496a5101d61d092\
5eeadea", "Text/1.0", "Text/1.0", None], OAuthSigning`Private`Token10[
  "806596495344603136-CEWIkGjWYevKFKsUT7uJ5XCLoLWyON2", 
  "NuE2kf4PjPNkzUCpb6dASqjMfMoXbE07ACTj7YImeMb1R"]]
```

I am not certain this will suffice for your purposes and this obviously requires a login step that you may not want.

The best option, however, may be to just write your own Twitter connection. I was able to build a connection to the StackExchange AP with OAuth and all in just a few hours and if you really need the flexibility, this is obvious the most flexible solution.

As dsingh points out, any solution that doesn't use toplevel/widespread functionality is likely to be unstable and so if you want a dependable solution that will work across versions/subversions of Mathematica, you're more-or-less restricted to building it yourself.