# Getting time zones by answer times

Tags: probability-or-statistics, date-and-time, webservices

So I built an [SE service connection](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147196/38205) and as a piece of pure curiosity I wanted to see if I could determine what a given user's time-zone was by the times which they answer.

I managed to pull in [all the answers](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-affd7b1c-ecb6-4ccc-8cc4-4d107e2bf04a/mse_answer_list.mx) using my [service connection](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-e4d1d43a-267f-4924-934a-2ba2321519a9/paclets/PacletServer/main.html#ServiceConnection_StackExchange).

And then I grouped the users and the hours of the day (in Unix time) when they answered and then I got stuck.

Because I can tell you when Mr. Wizard answers questions on average:

```
In[82]:= Mean@userTimes["Mr.Wizard"] // N

Out[82]= 11.6578
```

But this alone isn't enough to tell me what his(?) time-zone is (although per his/her profile it's PST: [image: mr.wizard time]).

And I can give you an [`EstimatedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EstimatedDistribution.html) (using [`NormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalDistribution.html)) of Kuba's answer times:

```
Plot[PDF[userDistributions["Kuba"], x], {x, -5, 30}]
```

[image: kuba dist]

But I don't know how to connect that to his time zone.

I know Mathematica should be able to give me this, maybe by comparing both the peak and the height in the distribution:

```
Plot[
 PDF[#, x] & /@ Take[userDistributions, 3] // Values // Evaluate,
 {x, -5, 30},
 PlotLabels -> Keys@Take[userDistributions, 3]
 ]
```

[image: top-three dist]

But this is simply not something I know enough about.

So can someone crack the code? As I have it set-up I suppose this breaks down to a statistical argument about how likely it is that a given user has a given time-zone, but is there a way to do this better than just that (if I even knew how to do that)?

Comment: I stumbled onto this today.  Some ideas: (1) I am male.  (2) I think many people often post at a couple of times each day (e.g. before and after work), so I would try a bimodal distribution for each profile to see if it fits better. (3) You should consider my data a pathological case (unfortunately, it is) – https://stackoverflow.com/a/5845444/618728

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up trying to use [`Classify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html) on this. First I pulled in [all of the users](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-affd7b1c-ecb6-4ccc-8cc4-4d107e2bf04a/mse_user_list.mx).

Then I found the ones where I could get a property city or admin. div. [`Entity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html):

```
$stateMap =
  AssociationThread[#,
     Interpreter["AdministrativeDivision"][#]
     ] &@DeleteDuplicates@Normal@users[All, "location"];

$cityMap =
  AssociationThread[#,
     Interpreter["City"][#]
     ] &@Keys@Select[$stateMap, FailureQ];

$locMap = 
  Join[Select[$cityMap, Not@*FailureQ], 
   Select[$stateMap, Not@*FailureQ]];

userLocs = 
  Association[
    First@# -> (Last@# /. $locMap) & /@ 
     Normal@users[All, {"display_name", "location"}]] // Dataset;

testableUsers = Select[userLocs, MatchQ[_Entity]];
```

Then I calculated the shifts from UTC for these users:

```
calcedShifts = <||>;

calcShit[ent_] :=
 Lookup[calcedShifts, ent,
  calcedShifts[ent] =
   Check[
      TimeZoneOffset[#],
      QuantityMagnitude[#["OffsetFromUTC"], "Hours"]
      ] &@
    If[EntityTypeName@ent === "AdministrativeDivision",
     First[ent["TimeZones"]],
     ent["TimeZone"]
     ]
  ]

userShifts = calcShit /@ Normal@testableUsers;
```

And then I built a classifier mapping the distribution parameters to the time-zone shift:

```
trainingSet =
  DeleteCases[
   Thread[
    Lookup[userDistParams,
      Normal@Keys[userShifts]] ->
     Normal@Values[userShifts]
    ],
   _Missing -> _
   ];

classifier = Classify[trainingSet];

timeZoneGuess[user_] :=

 classifier[userDistParams[user], "Probabilities"] // ReverseSort // 
  Dataset
timeZoneGuess[users : {__String}] :=

  Dataset@AssociationMap[Normal@timeZoneGuess[#] &, users];
```

And then we test:

```
In[349]:= 
Map[First@*Keys]@
  timeZoneGuess@Keys@Take[userDistributions, 15] // Normal

Out[349]= <|"Mr.Wizard" -> -5., "Michael E2" -> -5., 
 "m_goldberg" -> -5., "corey979" -> -5., "Szabolcs" -> 2., 
 "kglr" -> -5., "Bob Hanlon" -> -5., "ubpdqn" -> 2., "Kuba" -> 2., 
 "J. M." -> -5., "Carl Woll" -> -5., "george2079" -> -5., "zhk" -> 2.,
  "bill s" -> -5., "David G. Stork" -> -5.|>
```

And we find that it isn't so great... (obviously this is just the *most probable* time-zone guess from a fit to a [`NormalDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalDistribution.html). Using something more sophisticated might help.)

But it is certainly a start. And it does seem to classify America vs. Europe fine.

Comment: You have "circular" data. Perhaps you should consider using the Von Mises distribution, which is appropriate for such data. If it were me, I might go farther and compute non-parametric density estimates for each user, using the Von Mises distribution as the kernel.

Comment: @mef interesting suggestion. I'll give it a try when I have time.