# How to implement a free version of WebImageSearch?

Tags: image, web-access, webservices

I really don't like functions that I have to pay for, *if they can be implemented for free*.

Is there a way to get around this pay-wall for **WebImageSearch**? Perhaps using some other free api or service?

[image]

**Update:**

One idea I had was to use the french search engine Qwant which has an api which is free and unlimited for now: https://api.qwant.com/api/search/images?count=10&offset=1&q=cars (but has less accuracy than Google or Bing).

[image]

Comment: google images and bing images are both free...

Comment: or you can be the first one to implement and upload here :)

Comment: @M.R. I formalized the Qwant API into a service connection. See if it works for you.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Nice work, how can I see what options there are, e.g. is offset supported? `$so["ImageLinks", "q" -> "native american", "count" -> "10", 
 "page" -> 2]`

Comment: @M.R. I included everything I could quickly see. Doesn’t seem as if they API is documented. I’ll put in a note about how to extract those request parameters. I try to make sure they’re exposed in all of my connections.

Comment: @M.R. Done. Give it a look.

Comment: @b3m2a1 cool thx

Comment: @M.R. Does Quant API still work and has no limits?

Answer (score 14):

So after being wrong about Bing being free, we'll pursue my other suggestion, which was to use the [ServiceConnect framework](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147196/38205). I demonstrate how to use it in general [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/serviceconnections---mathematica-on-the-web.html#main-content).

For the purposes of this, though, here's what all you need to do. Get the paclet by running this:

```
(* 
  If you've already installed, replace this with PacletUpdate 
  to get the newest version
  *)
PacletInstall[
 "ServiceConnection_Qwant",
 "Site" -> 
  "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer"
 ]
```

Service connect like so:

```
$so = ServiceConnect["Qwant"]
```

[image: qwant]

And run it like so:

```
$so["ImageSearch", "q" -> "car", "count" -> "3"]
```

[image: result example]

I also provide access to the basic web search endpoint:

```
$so["WebSearch", "q" -> "pizza"]
```

[image: web search results]

---

#### Inspecting the `ServiceObject`

In all my service connections I include a way to access what parameters I've fed in. The request that implements this is called `"RequestParameters"`, named similarly to the `"Requests"` request that all `ServiceObject`s have by default. You use it like so:

```
$so["RequestParameters", "Request" -> "WebSearch"]

<|"Parameters" -> {"q", "count", "offset", "page"}, "Required" -> {}|>
```

(Note before v1.0.2 of this paclet this will return an empty list, as `"WebSearch"` really delegates to the standard `"Search"` method. Use `PacletUpdate` to get the newest version if you don't have it.)

**Update:**

I no longer can install this:

[image]

Comment: That's not true, see my update

Comment: @M.R. oh fascinating my ``IntegratedServices`ServiceCreditsAvailable`` is non-zero. Odd. I'll elaborate on the second, then.

Comment: Have you ever looked at implementing searching by image?  For example, find where a certain image appears on the web?

Comment: @Szabolcs I could try it, but I’m not sure it would go well. There’re no free APIs to work off of so I’d need to think hard about how to do it without it being unbearably slow. I think even this ImageSearch is too slow. I should really be using some async import for the thumbnails. Something like trying to get a guess for the image with ImageIdentify then using iterated searches for similar images would be brutally slow and prone to error.

Comment: There is a glitch: current version still pops-up the ["Sign in with your wolfram ID" dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZFEr.png) (although it works after closing the dialog without signing in).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov ah yeah I'm sure something in my framework is checking for your `$WolframID` at some point. I forget that not everyone has cloud accounts... (I currently have like 4 free ones; each for a different purpose). I'll fix it when I have time.

Comment: Can someone just update the code for this answer so it works?

Comment: @M.R. I think WRI obliterated my packet server. The underlying packet mechanisms changed and I don’t really do Mathematica dev anymore. Maybe once the proper repo is out I’ll revisit my package framework and update my tools so they work again but as is I just don’t have the incentives

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Perhaps you could update it and submit to  this new thing: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/published/PacletRepository/index

Comment: @M.R. I asked Bob S. for access but have yet to get it. When I get access I’ll see what I can do