# Web search browser in Mathematica

Tags: customization, web-access, interface

How can we build a system to perform web searches (e.g. Google search) in a notebook so that it looks and functions like a normal search interface operating in the browser?

Answer (score 10):

I started on this, after building out a search paclet for [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158142/38205).

The basic idea is to simply provide nicer access to the basic underlying paclet. The code all lives [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/SearchBrowser.wl).

We can use it like so:

```
Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/master/SearchBrowser.wl"];
SearchBrowser[]
```

[image: empty browser]

And then just type and search:

[image: search example]

One convenient thing is that we can dynamically bind the search results, and use the different types of search (such as video):

```
SearchBrowser[Dynamic[sr]]
```

[image: cat result]

and then we can still access the results outside of the interface:

```
sr[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: I admire your productivity and the ability to stay focused to bring your projects to a usable point. +1

Comment: @Kuba it's the power of procrastination :)

Comment: Ah, so you have something more important to do? Makes sense :)

Comment: Not working for me. E.g., if I try your example of searching Web for Qwant, I get an error message: "ServiceConnect: The service Qwant is unknown, try providing authentication options."  Is there something more I need to do besides loading `SearchBrowser.wl`?

Comment: @murray Hm... the `Initialization` clearly isn't doing its job. It's trying to install the `Qwant` paclet. If you use the `PacletInstall` from the linked answer then try again it will work.

Comment: @murray Try it again now. It turns out it was a context issue.

Comment: OK now with fixed version, thanks.