# Dynamic WebImageSearch

Tags: dynamic, web-access, webservices

I am a little bit lost here, I'd be really grateful if someone could help me. :) We are working on a "video" (actually images with transitions).

We are having a list of specific words eg.:

```
List = {apple, tree, house, dog}
```

(but these words can change every time when we import an another text), so everything is pretty much dynamic.

So that we are having a specific list of words and we would like to use these words to find images this way:

```
WebImageSearch["word1", "Thumbnails", "MaxItems" -> 1]
WebImageSearch["word2", "Thumbnails", "MaxItems" -> 1]
WebImageSearch["word3", "Thumbnails", "MaxItems" -> 1]
```

... so that, I guess:

```
WebImageSearch[dynamic-image, "Thumbnails", "MaxItems" -> 1]
```

where dynamic-image has to be dynamic.

Also is it possible to do it with not WebImageSearch, but something free (eg. with an api)? That would be absolutely be the best! :)

Thanks you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update:

here's the same, but better and in a package on GitHub now:

```
Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/master/DynamicWebImage.wl"]

i = Last[animals];
DynamicWebImageBrowser[Dynamic[i], animals]
```

[image: crabby]

---

Here's a way to do this for free with the Qwant API:

```
dynamicWebImage[
  imgVar_Dynamic, 
  caching : True | False : True, 
  ops : OptionsPattern[Join[Options@DynamicModule, Options@Image]]
  ] :=
 DynamicModule[
  {img},
  Replace[
   imgVar, {
    Verbatim[Dynamic][var_, o___?OptionQ] :>
     Dynamic[
      img =
       Image[
        dynamicWebImage`Private`qwantSingleSearch[var, caching]["Image"],
        FilterRules[{ops},
         Options@Image
         ]
        ],
      o],
    Verbatim[Dynamic][var_, f : Except[_?OptionQ], o___?OptionQ] :>
     Dynamic[
      img =
       Image[
        Last@Through[

          Flatten[List@f][
           dynamicWebImage`Private`qwantSingleSearch[var, caching]]
          ],
        FilterRules[{ops},
         Options@Image
         ]
        ],
      o
      ]
    }],
  Initialization :>
   {
    OptionValue[Initialization],
    If[! AssociationQ@dynamicWebImage`Private`$qwantCache, 
     dynamicWebImage`Private`$qwantCache = <||>
     ],
    dynamicWebImage`Private`qwantSingleSearch[ 
      q_String?(StringLength[StringTrim[#]] > 0 &),
      cached : True | False : True] :=
     Replace[
      dynamicWebImage`Private`$qwantCache[q],
      Except[_Association?(KeyMemberQ["Image"])]:>
       With[{
         r =
          First@Normal@
           dynamicWebImage`Private`qwantInstance["ImageSearch", 
            "q" -> q, "count" -> "1"]
         },
        If[cached, dynamicWebImage`Private`$qwantCache[q] = r, r]
        ]
      ],
    dynamicWebImage`Private`qwantSingleSearch[__] :=
     None,
    If[! TrueQ[dynamicWebImage`Private`qwantPacletUpdated],
     If[Length@PacletManager`PacletFind["ServiceConnection_Qwant"] > 0,
       PacletInstall,
       PacletUpdate
       ][
      "ServiceConnection_Qwant", 
      "Site" -> 
       "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/\
PacletServer"
      ];
     dynamicWebImage`Private`qwantPacletUpdated = 
      Length@PacletManager`PacletFind["ServiceConnection_Qwant"] > 0
     ],
    dynamicWebImage`Private`qwantInstance = ServiceConnect["Qwant"]
    },
  Evaluate[
   Sequence @@ FilterRules[{
      ops
      },
     Options@DynamicModule
     ]
   ],
  SynchronousInitialization->True
  ]
```

This just sets up a little framework to work with [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158142/38205).

Here's a fun example of what you can do with it:

```
animals =
  Cases[
   Import[
    "https://www.livescience.com/13524-500-cutest-animals-list.html",
    {"HTML", "XMLObject"}
    ],
   XMLElement["p", _,
     {a_String?(StringStartsQ[Whitespace ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ "."])}
     ] :>
    StringTrim@
     First@StringSplit[Last@StringSplit[a, ". "], "(" | " aka "],
   \[Infinity]];
a = Last@animals;

Framed[
 Column[{
   Panel[
    InputField[Dynamic[a],
     String,
     MenuList -> animals
     ],
    ImageSize -> 350,
    Appearance ->
     Lookup[
      FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", 
       "MoreLeftSetterNinePatchAppearance"],
      "Hover"
      ],
    Alignment -> Center
    ],
   dynamicWebImage[
    Dynamic[a],
    ImageSize -> 350,
    DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> Infinity
    ]
   },
  Spacings -> 0
  ],
 FrameMargins -> None,
 FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.85]
 ]
```

[image: asdasd]

Note that that's really just so much formatting around:

```
dynamicWebImage[
 Dynamic[a],
 ImageSize -> 350,
 DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> Infinity
 ]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69095/discussion-on-answer-by-b3m2a1-dynamic-webimagesearch).