# dynamicWebImage - apply filters on images

Tags: list-manipulation, image-processing, dynamic

I really need some professional help! :)
I am having some problem with styling things inside DynamicModule. In this case I would like to eg. apply filters to the images that I get after running my code. I am using Qwant and I get images dynamically according to words that I have.

How could I apply filters to the images that I get?

```
  DynamicModule[{},
     Column[{

    ....

    dynamicWebImage[
     Dynamic[f],
     ImageSize -> 600,
     DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> Infinity]
    ....

    }]]
```

Details and background info: [Dynamic WebImageSearch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160296/dynamic-webimagesearch)

Thank you very much!

Fanni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that answer you'll notice I defined the call like so:

```
dynamicWebImage[
  imgVar_Dynamic, 
  caching : True | False : True, 
  ops : OptionsPattern[Join[Options@DynamicModule, Options@Image]]
  ]
```

In the code I let whatever you supplied as the second argument to `Dynamic` operate on the Qwant results.

For instance;

```
a = "Sea Otter";
dynamicWebImage[Dynamic[a, ColorConvert[#["Image"], "Grayscale"] &]]
```

[image: filtered]

I believe this is what you mean by "applying filters". So hopefully that will get the job done.

Comment: Perfect, thank you sooo much! :)