# How to get all elements from a single WebImageSearch[]?

Tags: image, webservices

I'm trying to use [WebImageSearch[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WebImageSearch.html) to get a bunch of images and basic metadata about them. According to the documentation, we can get the following info:

[image]

Is it possible to get all of these for a single query/search? For instance, I tried doing the following, but it does not work:

`WebImageSearch["cats", {"Images", "ImageHyperlinks", "PageTitles", "PageHyperlinks"}, MaxItems -> 4]`

Only individual elements give the proper results:

[image]

This would be important to save service credits, as these searches can cost a lot with the amount of searches I'd like to do.

Thank you!

Comment: There is a paclet that can do something like (using Qwant) described here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158134/how-to-implement-a-free-version-of-webimagesearch?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Seems as only single elements can be obtained by Import

```
     cats = WebImageSearch["cats", "ImageHyperlinks", MaxItems -> 4]

     el = Import[cats[[1]], {"Elements"}]
```

So I import per map into the elements

```
      Import[cats[[1, 1]] , #] & /@ el[[{1, 3, 5, 6, 10, 10, 12}]]
```

{8, 3, ColorProfileData[NumericArray[CompressedData["..."],"UnsignedInteger8"], "RGB", "XYZ"], "RGB", <|"Make" -> "Canon",
"Model" -> "Canon EOS 5D Mark III", "XResolution" -> 240,
"YResolution" -> 240, "ResolutionUnit" -> "Inch",
"Software" -> "Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 4.1 (Windows)",
"DateTime" ->
DateObject[{2012, 10, 7, 20, 50, 1.}, "Instant", "Gregorian",
None], "ExposureTime" -> Quantity[1/200, "Seconds"],
"FNumber" -> "f/2.8", "ExifTag" -> 214,
"ExposureProgram" -> "Manual", "ISOSpeedRatings" -> 1600,
"SensitivityType" -> "Recommended Exposure Index",
"RecommendedExposureIndex" -> 1600, "ExifVersion" -> "2.30",
"DateTimeOriginal" ->
DateObject[{2012, 2, 14, 17, 56, 7.}, "Instant", "Gregorian",
None], "DateTimeDigitized" ->
DateObject[{2012, 2, 14, 17, 56, 7.}, "Instant", "Gregorian",
None], "ShutterSpeedValue" ->
Quantity[477741/62500, IndependentUnit["exposure values"]],
"ApertureValue" ->
Quantity[1485427/500000, IndependentUnit["exposure values"]],
"ExposureBiasValue" ->
Quantity[0, IndependentUnit["exposure values"]],
"MaxApertureValue" ->
Quantity[3., IndependentUnit["exposure values"]],
"MeteringMode" -> "Multi-segment",
"FlashInfo" -> <|"FlashUsed" -> False,
"FlashFiringStatus" -> "No strobe return detection function",
"FlashMode" -> "Compulsory flash firing",
"FlashFunctionPresent" -> True, "RedEyeCorrection" -> False|>,
"FocalLength" -> Quantity[185., "Millimeters"],
"SubSecTimeOriginal" -> "00", "SubSecTimeDigitized" -> "00",
"FocalPlaneXResolution" -> 160, "FocalPlaneYResolution" -> 160,
"FocalPlaneResolutionUnit" -> "Millimeter",
"CustomRendered" -> "Normal", "ExposureMode" -> "Manual",
"WhiteBalance" -> Automatic, "SceneCaptureType" -> "Standard",
"BodySerialNumber" -> "062124001701",
"LensSpecification" -> {70, 200, Indeterminate, Indeterminate},
"LensModel" -> "EF70-200mm f/2.8L USM",
"LensSerialNumber" -> "0000000000"|>, <|"Make" -> "Canon",
"Model" -> "Canon EOS 5D Mark III", "XResolution" -> 240,
"YResolution" -> 240, "ResolutionUnit" -> "Inch",
"Software" -> "Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 4.1 (Windows)",
"DateTime" ->
DateObject[{2012, 10, 7, 20, 50, 1.}, "Instant", "Gregorian",
None], "ExposureTime" -> Quantity[1/200, "Seconds"],
"FNumber" -> "f/2.8", "ExifTag" -> 214,
"ExposureProgram" -> "Manual", "ISOSpeedRatings" -> 1600,
"SensitivityType" -> "Recommended Exposure Index",
"RecommendedExposureIndex" -> 1600, "ExifVersion" -> "2.30",
"DateTimeOriginal" ->
DateObject[{2012, 2, 14, 17, 56, 7.}, "Instant", "Gregorian",
None], "DateTimeDigitized" ->
DateObject[{2012, 2, 14, 17, 56, 7.}, "Instant", "Gregorian",
None], "ShutterSpeedValue" ->
Quantity[477741/62500, IndependentUnit["exposure values"]],
"ApertureValue" ->
Quantity[1485427/500000, IndependentUnit["exposure values"]],
"ExposureBiasValue" ->
Quantity[0, IndependentUnit["exposure values"]],
"MaxApertureValue" ->
Quantity[3., IndependentUnit["exposure values"]],
"MeteringMode" -> "Multi-segment",
"FlashInfo" -> <|"FlashUsed" -> False,
"FlashFiringStatus" -> "No strobe return detection function",
"FlashMode" -> "Compulsory flash firing",
"FlashFunctionPresent" -> True, "RedEyeCorrection" -> False|>,
"FocalLength" -> Quantity[185., "Millimeters"],
"SubSecTimeOriginal" -> "00", "SubSecTimeDigitized" -> "00",
"FocalPlaneXResolution" -> 160, "FocalPlaneYResolution" -> 160,
"FocalPlaneResolutionUnit" -> "Millimeter",
"CustomRendered" -> "Normal", "ExposureMode" -> "Manual",
"WhiteBalance" -> Automatic, "SceneCaptureType" -> "Standard",
"BodySerialNumber" -> "062124001701",
"LensSpecification" -> {70, 200, Indeterminate, Indeterminate},
"LensModel" -> "EF70-200mm f/2.8L USM",
"LensSerialNumber" -> "0000000000"|>, None}

Its perhaps not a bad idea, to strip all metadata from jpgs before publishing. Its possible to track any camera body in space and time.

Comment: Interesting, that's quite a bit of data I didn't know would be able to get. Would this method use more credits than simply doing separate searches with the same search terms but different "element" queries?

Comment: Import does not use credits, it just imports data like a browser.

Comment: Ohh, I see. So this still relies on WebImageSearch[] for gathering the images and then gets the metadata. Good to know, but I'm mostly interested in fetching the images, url, and the other info that's supposed to be obtained with WebImageSearch[]. Thanks!