# How can I access NASA images and APIs?

Tags: webservices

I ♥ NASA. You ♥ NASA. We all ♥ NASA.

So how can I use the images and things they expose in [their APIs](https://api.nasa.gov/index.html) in Mathematica?

Answer (score 40):

I built a `ServiceConnect` paclet for this (details on how I did this can be found at the end of this post).

You can access it like so:

```
PacletInstall[
 "ServiceConnection_NASA",
 "Site"->
  "http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/PacletServer"
 ]
```

[image: paclet]

*(note that unless you have [BTools](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools) installed and have loaded the PacletTools package (e.g. by just calling `PacletUpload` raw to get the autoloader to run) you won't get this formatted form)*

Then just connect and have at it!

```
$so = ServiceConnect["NASA"]
```

[image: nasdasdasd]

#### Pic of the Day

```
$so["PictureOfTheDay"]["Image"]
```

[image: nasa img]

#### Earth

```
$so["EarthImages",
  "Date" -> Today - Quantity[1, "Weeks"], 
  "ImportImages" -> True,
  "ImportSelection" -> ;; 3
  ][All, {"Image", "caption"}]
```

[image: images]

#### Mars

```
$so["MarsImages", 
  "earth_date" -> Today, "ImportImages" -> True, 
  "ImportSelection" -> {1}
  ][2]
```

[image: asdasd]

#### And more!

You can get the currently supported requests like so:

```
$so["Requests"]

{"APIKey", "Authentication", "EarthImages", "ID", \
"ImportEarthImages", "Information", "LandsatAssets", "LandsatImages", \
"MarsImage", "MarsRoverData", "Name", "NeoFeed", "NeoLookup", \
"Patents", "PictureOfTheDay", "RawRequests", "RequestData", \
"RequestParameters", "RoverCameras"}
```

And you can figure out what to pass to each using the `"RequestParameters"` like so:

```
$so["RequestParameters", "Request" -> "Patents"]

<|"Parameters" -> {"api_key", "query", "concept_tags", "limit"}, 
 "Required" -> {}|>

$so["Patents"]["results", 1, "title"]

"Selective functionalization of carbon nanotubes based upon distance  \
   traveled"
```

If you want me to implement more requests I can easily do so

---

## Construction Process

I built this according to the process laid out in [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147196/38205) to the question [Creating a custom web API ServiceConnection](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146915/creating-a-custom-web-api-serviceconnection?rq=1).

The actual construction notebook can be obtained [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.services/ServiceConnections/NASAServiceTemplate.nb) so you can see what went into building it.

Essentially, I just have a template notebook that you fill out and which formats a call to the [`CustomServiceConnection`](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/Packages/CustomServiceConnection.m) function in my [BTools package](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools).

Comment: I love NASA⊙ Also.

Comment: +1 of course but please include at least the very initial implementation. We try to avoid link based answers as they can become useless once links are invalid. Would be also nice to link BTools if you mention them.

Comment: @Kuba that's handled. I didn't go into the actual gory details but mostly just linked to a construction notebook and my previous answer on building `ServiceConnections`

Comment: @b3m2a1 'How to' overview is handled but the answer is still only on wofram cloud.

Comment: @Kuba unfortunately a proper run-down of everything involved in that template notebook won't really illuminate much I think. The "initial implementation" was just I looked through their API docs and filled in my template.

Comment: It is not about illumination but a self contained content. Once your wolfram cloud account is gone this answer won't be so helpful.

Comment: @Kuba I get that, but similarly once my GitHub repo disappears this won't be salvageable. I'm all for fighting link rot, but I don't really know how to balance that with not dumping a whole slew of generally unparseable muck into the answer / staying under the character limit for answers.

Comment: @b3m2a1 You are right, it is not a must so let's stay with more example focused answers linked together with github and wpc.