# Problem accessing NASA images

Tags: web-access

There seems to be a problem with the last version (11.2 on MacOS X) of Mathematica when trying to access NASA images and APIs using the ServiceConnect paclet [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163638/how-can-i-access-nasa-images-and-apis) buit by [b3m2a1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38205/b3m2a1).

While paclet intallation seems to work:

[image]

unfortunately, access to material does not work:

[image]

What makes me suspect a problem with Mathematica is that going to :

https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=p5MIR64KG838qZjMCmnjdQeIXLYzNLuPAZWvQ94j

I get access to the "*Image of the day*" description :

[image]

which I can then download without problem...

This shows that I can access the NASA API and that the problem seems to come from my version of Mathematica...

As **URLFetch** has been superseded by **URLRead** and **URLExecute** since version 11 could this be the origin of the problem ?

Does anyone else meet the same issue ?

Comment: It's probably good to list that you're in Version 11.2, too. As for the superseding issue, that shouldn't be an issue as most service connections still use `URLFetch` as some level. Can you use `URLFetch` on any URLs?

Comment: Yes, I did state already that I am on version 11.2 on Mac OSX and yes, **URLFetch** works for me, I tested it already on several websites.