# How to get satellite image directly from Mathematica?

Tags: image-processing, files-and-directories, web-access, api, url

First, I get the image of the bands of the desired area from the site https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/, then I import the images into Mathmatica by addressing them as below:

Select dataset directory:

```
imgdir = 
  FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
    "Sacramento Area Data 07-10-2018"}];
```

Import bands without Atmospheric Correction in DN (with Radiometric correction):

```
{bandIR, bandR, bandG, bandB} = 
  Import[FileNameJoin[{imgdir, 
       "LC08_L1TP_044033_20181007_20200830_02_T1_B" <> ToString[#] <> 
        ".TIF"}], "Data"] & /@ {5, 4, 3, 2};
```

Show green band raw image:

```
5 ImageAdjust[Image[bandG, ImageSize -> Medium]]
```

[image]

This operation is not automatic and must be downloaded from the Usgs and then entered into Mathematica by addressing. My question is, is it possible to go directly from Mathematica to https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/
and get a satellite image?

Comment: There was this API that has LandsatImages as a request option, but I don't know anything about and have never used it https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163639/72953

Comment: It seems that USGS provide an [API](https://m2m.cr.usgs.gov/) to access their data inventories. There is also a [python library](http://kapadia.github.io/usgs/index.html) which you may use to call from Mathematica ... Read the documentation of the API, and then use 
[`HTTPRequest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HTTPRequest.html) etc. to access it.