# How to take a satellite image in Mathematica at different times?

Tags: image-processing, image, date-and-time, geographics

I want to see the satellite image of the same area at different times. But by entering the following code, also shows the same picture with changing times.

```
image = GeoImage[GeoPosition[{37.668317, -106.203445}], 
  GeoZoomLevel -> 10.75, 
  ImageResolution -> 200, {"Date" -> DateObject[{2010, 7, 5}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: There is no "Date" option for GeoImage. Therefore, you can not get an image for an arbitrary  date.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica has a rich set of image file formats that can be ingested, manipulated and displayed.  It is a bit more work, but I would suggest acquiring the time-series imagery from the US Geological Survey.  You can use their website (https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-data-access) or API to get the data you seek manually and then processing it.  There is a short thread on the API interface at the end of this article:

[How to get satellite image directly from Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288844/how-to-get-satellite-image-directly-from-mathematica)