# Using OAuthClient to extend ServiceConnect service that requires authentication and POST

Tags: undocumented, webservices, authentication

I want to extend the functionality of a service available via [`ServiceConnect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ServiceConnect.html), particularly Google Calendar to insert a new event.

That action requieres authentication via OAuth2, and that can be done by

```
googlecalendar = ServiceConnect["GoogleCalendar"]
```

The Google API documentation is available here

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

It indicates that to create an event one needs to `POST` a body like this

```
{
  "end": {
    "date": "2018-06-19"
  },
  "start": {
    "date": "2018-06-18"
  }
}
```

I don't know how to use the already authenticated service connection to `POST` my request. I'm guessing that `` OAuthClient`rawoauthdata `` should help.

I know this code does not work, but I would like to do something like

```
Module[
{
id=googlecalendar["ID"],
calendarId= "calendarIdString",
url,
body="{
  \"end\": {
    \"date\": \"2018-06-19\"
  },
  \"start\": {
    \"date\": \"2018-06-18\"
  }
}"
},
url=StringTemplate[
 "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/`1`/events/insert"
][calendarId];
OAuthClient`rawoauthdata[
 id,
 url,
 { 
  "method" -> "POST",
  "body" -> body
 }
 ]
]
```

**EDIT**

As per suggestion by @b3m2a1, I'm open to the possibility of editing the *paclet* itself, even if that seems to me implies a much more serious task of making the new function consistent with the rest.

In any of the two cases I'm missing the intermediate information that links the high level and still cryptic `OAuthClient` with the low level construction of a `URLFetch` call, defining proper headers, body and so on. I don't understand how they relate, and all the examples I can see in other programming languages are high level.

So, I'm restating my question, inside or outside the *paclet*,

**How to implement a function that uses *POST* and *OAuth* to achieve inserting an event in Google Calendar?**

Comment: I suggest editing the paclet directly. It's really quite easy to do. See, [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146915/creating-a-custom-web-api-serviceconnection?noredirect=1&lq=1) for instance (and just edit the existing one instead of making a new one). Or duplicate the existing one and make a `"GCal"` connection or something which you can customize at will.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks for the suggestion. I'm afraid that *"really quite easy to do"*  it's in the eye of the experienced beholder. I haven't been able to understand it, yet. I updated my question to explicitly say that my vacuum in knowledge is the link between a low level *headers and body* http call, and for me impenetrable `OAuthClient` functions, for which I can't find much understandable information.

Comment: Of course. It's only approaching *quite easy* if you spent a full day or so deconstructing these paclets. I'll post a template answer to get you started.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an elaboration on my suggestion. More information on why I'm doing what I'm doing is here: [Creating a custom web API ServiceConnection](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146915/creating-a-custom-web-api-serviceconnection?noredirect=1&lq=1)

First open the paclet:

```
SystemOpen @ PacletFind["*_GoogleCalendar"][[1]]["Location"]
```

Go into the `GoogleCalendar.m` file and make the following changes:

Add `"RawPosts"->{"RawCalendarInsert"}` and `"Posts"->{"CalendarInsert"}` to the lists of supported requests (under `googlecalendardata`)

Then add a raw data request template that looks like:

```
googlecalendardata["RawCalendarInsert"] =
 {
  "URL" -> (
    TemplateApply[
      StringForm[
       "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/`1`/events", 
       URLEncode[#]]
      ] &),
  "PathParameters" -> {"calendarID"},
  "RequiredParameters" -> {"calendarID", "start", "end"},
  "HTTPSMethod" -> "POST",
  "BodyData" -> {"start", "end"},
  "ResultsFunction" -> googlecalendarimport
  }
```

And finally add a cooked data function that basically just calls this:

```
googlecalendarcookeddata["CalendarInsert", id_, args_] :=

 Block[
  {rawdata, invalidParameters, cId, fieldnames, result},
  If[KeyExistsQ[args, "CalendarID"],
   cId = Lookup[args, "CalendarID"];
   If[! MatchQ[cId, _String],
    Message[ServiceExecute::nval, "CalendarID", "GoogleCalendar"];
    Throw[$Failed]
    ],
   Message[ServiceExecute::nparam, "CalendarID"];
   Throw[$Failed]
   ];
  rawdata =
   OAuthClient`rawoauthdata[id, 
    "RawCalendarInsert", {"calendarID" -> ToString[cId]}];
  result = googlecalendarimport[rawdata]
  ]
```

You can pretty up that function however you so choose.

You may need to do a reset of the data for this to get the changes to merge. To do that run:

```
Quiet[
 Once[OAuthClient`Private`oauthservicesdata["GoogleCalendar"]] =.;
 ServiceDisconnect["GoogleCalendar"];
 ServiceConnections`Private`findandloadServicePaclet["GoogleCalendar"];
 ]
```

Make sure to preserve any changes you make somewhere as if WRI updates its paclet you'll need to reapply them (but it looks like they haven't in over a year).

You can also simply duplicate the entire paclet and change only the name in the `PacletInfo.m` file (to say `GoogleCalendar2`) or something. Then run `RebuildPacletData` and you can use that edited paclet.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I have (https://pastebin.com/raw/qqXGCMfU) and I'm unsure how to call it. It complains "ServiceExecute::nparam: The parameter start is required" , when it's present. `googlecalendar["CalendarInsert", 
 "CalendarID" -> "xxxIDxxx", "start" -> "2018-06-21", 
 "end" -> "2018-06-23"]`

Comment: @rhermans Ah shit. Forgot to include the `args` part. When it calls the `rawoauthdata` you’ll need to include the `args` other than the calendar ID.