# How to download user faves on Flickr?

Tags: image, webservices, api, serviceexecute, url

The Flickr service API doesn’t seem to have the [getfavorites()](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getFavorites.html) request implemented. Is there an good way to do this with `WebExecute`?

**Code to get started with:**

For a given user, say *7944912@N05*, there are *n* pages for which one can manually extract images:

```
s = StartWebSession[];

WebExecute[s, 
 "OpenPage" -> 
  "https://www.flickr.com/photos/7944912@N05/favorites/page1/"]

possibleimageurls = WebExecute[s, "PageHyperlinks"];
Length@possibleimageurls

i = Import@
   "https://live.staticflickr.com/4278/34611590423_5f44dc95d2_k.jpg";
{Thumbnail@i, ImageDimensions[i]}
```

[image]

But I don't know how to enumerate the highest resolution ones.

Comment: Easier is probably to patch the `ServiceConnect` paclet to add the request. That on its own isn't too hard. Just find the paclet with `PacletFind` and figure out where they implement all their requests.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Open the paclet with `PacletFind["ServiceConnect_Flickr"]["Location"]`. There’ll be a Kernel folder. Inside that there should be like Flickr.m or something. That’s where all the API requests are implemented.

Comment: I wrote up a Q/A about how to work with service connect packets here a few years back

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks, but PacletFind["ServiceConnect_Flickr"] gives {}, is there a link to your tutorial?

Comment: @b3m2a1 Would you be able to point me to your tutorial?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146915/38205 that explains the format of the packets

Comment: @b3m2a1  thanks, and what is the paclet called if not “ServiceConnect_Flickr”?

Comment: Try `PacletFind["Service*_*Fl*]`

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a full answer**

As @b3m2a1 suggested, I looked into the paclet and tried updating the functions:

```
p = PacletFind["Service*_*Fl*"]
p[[1]]["Location"]
```

[image]

Which looks like this:

[image]

Then I added this to `Flickr.m`:

```
 flickrdata["RawFaves"] := {
    "URL"                -> "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?method=flickr.favorites.getlist",
    "HTTPSMethod"        -> "GET",
    "Parameters"        -> {"user_id","tags","tag_mode","text","min_upload_date","max_upload_date",
                            "min_taken_date","max_taken_date","license","sort","privacy_filter","bbox",
                            "accuracy","safe_search","content_type","machine_tags","machine_tag_mode",
                            "group_id","contacts","woe_id","place_id","media","has_geo","geo_context",
                            "lat","lon","radius","radius_units","is_commons","in_gallery","is_getty",
                            "extras","per_page","page","format","nojsoncallback","jsoncallback"},
    "RequiredParameters"-> {},
    "ReturnContentData" -> True,
    "ResultsFunction"    -> flickrimport
}
```

Then I restarted the kernel, configure the connection again (which there was a way to save between restarts):

```
PacletUpdate[p[[1]]]
f = ServiceConnect["Flickr"]
```

and tried it out:

```
results = 
 f["RawFaves", "user_id" -> "97408942@N04", "per_page" -> "2", 
  "page" -> "1", "format" -> "json", "nojsoncallback" -> "1"]
```

[image]

Q: *How do I get it to return the original sized images?*

Comment: @b3m2a1 `PacletUpdate` is now obsolete, and this stopped working in v12.1... any ideas?